# How do I fix the "ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE" error that happens when sending a request between docker containers?

Tags: angular, spring, docker, docker-compose

The vps has 3 docker containers with backend (Spring), frontend (Angular) and database (Postgres). For addressing between containers I use internal IP docker network.
When addressing from Spring to db at "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.4/16" there are no problems.
But when I make a request from the front to the backend at "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.2/16", an error comes back:

`GET https://172.24.0.2:8080/api/v1/ net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`

What could be the problem? And how to fix it?

```
[
    {
        "Name": "custom_network",
        "Id": "3baf05ce8f75a01362969f91e78c57d0cfa79722d7072575202e12375a7b9174",
        "Created": "2023-04-25T09:13:50.877460737+03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.24.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.24.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "397c9c4e3a0db97d01f6a1caec7badfd5c9d4c9bb41d12a11db3c4959ea9154d": {
                "Name": "backend",
                "EndpointID": "0b61ce825a240de60606be6abf0f8be4f943b9f8b0e7a2834c0ee72b0281c842",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:18:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c35305b9272d42332475964c6556c7236290b8c05cce67185b74cdca6012a412": {
                "Name": "postgres",
                "EndpointID": "7baf108af5f4e8ebf437a3365de8c5a75235b184d627159138cfbdba560d4793",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:18:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "fe3d07eb78c02717b9b816852a13280652eca0bc593d48746292fe6d0fb11c22": {
                "Name": "frontend",
                "EndpointID": "f702828c1ceede8585fd4f33feaac544da2f706734dd88c5543c9a5cb291fd4c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:18:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "custom",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.15.1"
        }
    }
]
```

I tried creating my own docker network and linking all the containers there manually, but that didn't work either.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
    556baf78f70a   angular    "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   14 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes   0.0.0.0:443->80/tcp, :::443->80/tcp         info-pet-angular_app-1
    a2d516c5ec0d   backend   "java -jar backend.j…"   43 minutes ago   Up 43 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   info-pet-app-1
    55b067ff2ad2   postgres              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 hours ago      Up 6 hours      5432/tcp                                    infopet-postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the internal IP (172.24.0.2) directly in the Angular frontend code because the frontend runs in the browser, not within the Docker network. From the browsers perspective, the container IP address and port are not reachable.

To fix this issue, you simply need to expose the backend container's port (8080) to the host machine and use the host's IP address or domain name to access the backend from the frontend. After that you should be able to call your backend from the Angular code through http://localhost:8080/api/v1/

Comment: The frontend has ssl certification enabled and there is a mixed content error if the host's IP address is accessed. I tried to open port 8080 (by expose: -8080), but still get the error CONNECTION REFUSED